# How to find first '1' in every row in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, find

I have a matrix,

```
A = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
```

My question is, how to find the first '1' in each row. I want the output will show like this:

```
B = [7; 6; 7]
```

Meaning that, for the first row, the number 1 found on column number 7, second row found in column number 6 and so on.

Comment: Read about [find](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the second output of [`max`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html), which gives the position of the maximum:

```
v = 1; % desired value
[~, B] = max(A==v, [], 2); % position of maxima along the second dimension
```

As a bonus, if there can be rows that don't contain the desired value, you can output `0` for those rows as follows:

```
[m, B] = max(A==v, [], 2);
B = B.*m;
```

Answer (score 4):

Find [cumulative sum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) of each row of `A` and use [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the row and column subscripts of ones and then order the column subscripts according to rows to get the desired matrix `B`.

```
[rind,cind] = find(cumsum(A,2)==1);
[~, rind] = unique(rind);
B = cind(rind);
```